# Which is the best layout for the table and row views, I can edit, delete, and updated data in each table based on row like in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android application I want to create a table which will populate data from SQlite and show in a table with rows, columns, and then I want to edit, modify data in each column based on rows. I also want to disappear row after finishing modifications with click on a button. My question is, which layout should I use, Table layout or Grid view/layout????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Table Layout. Although it uses table row as its child, you can actually use any View subclass as the child. Also, for your purposes, there is a lot of examples online for using a TableLayout and populating it with data from SQLite. A nice thing about the tableLayout is that it manages each row nicely in terms of sizing.